# Broken DAG: [link] cannot import name 'FileSensor'

Tags: etl, airflow

I'm getting this error on the airflow UI. the code line I've entered is:
***from airflow.contrib.sensors.file_sensor import FileSensor***
any ideas?
found nothing on google.

thanks

Comment: which version of Airflow are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an Airflow version < 1.10, e.g. 1.9?
In that case, try the following:

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.fs_operator import FileSensor
```

I tried this in v1.10.9 and the following both work.

```
from airflow.contrib.sensors.file_sensor import FileSensor
from airflow.contrib.operators.fs_operator import FileSensor
```

See the following links for reference:

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-9-stable/airflow/contrib/operators/fs_operator.py
[https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-9-stable/airflow/contrib/operators/**init**.py](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-9-stable/airflow/contrib/operators/__init__.py)